# How do I import a swift file in another

Tags: swift

how do I import a swift file in another swift file so I could use variables. Here is my code from *menuViewController.swift* and I want to use variable  *selectedObject*

```
import UIKit

    class menuViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var selectedObject: String!
}
```

I want to use the variable from above file in *ViewController.swift*. Here is my *ViewController.sswift*

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIAlertViewDelegate {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If they are in the same target you do not need to import other Swift files.

```
import UIKit

class MenuViewController: UIViewController {

    var selectedObject: String!
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let menuViewController = MenuViewController()


    func doSomething() {
        menuViewController.selectedObject = "foo"
    }
}
```

The above is working fine for me.

Comment: what do you mean by same target? ... I have only one target, so how should I check if it's the same

Comment: If you have only one, then you should be fine. You can check Target Membership in the Utilities pane. http://i.imgur.com/hXAxqu4.png

Comment: I have all swift files listed in Target's Compile sources section.. Take a look here http://postimg.org/image/xlr9h77bj/

Comment: Can you post to imgur or dropbox? That domain is blocked at my office

Answer (score 1):

All you need todo is import the project. So say if your project is called my project, do:

```
import myproject
```